# PHP retrieving all Node names and node values from a nested XML string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Trying to find a way to read an XML file and get all the nodes. 
Some of the XML files have 1 step depth, others 2, others more.
Is there anyway to get all the nodes for all children without knowing their name?
e.g. i wrote this piece of code but this works only for 2 steps depth

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $node) {
        if ($node->children()->count()>0) {
            foreach ($node->children() as $cnode){
                echo $cnode->getName()."<br>";
            }
        }
        echo $node->getName()."<br>";
    }
```

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <multitrans xmlns="http://www.xxxx.xx/">
         <authentication>
            <username>xxxxxx</username>
            <password>xxxxxx</password>
            <clientid>xxxxxx</clientid>
         </authentication>
         <requests>
            <trans_request>
               <TransType tc="100"/>
               <company tc="500"/>
               <product tc="auto"/>
               <inception>
                  <p_year>2017</p_year>
                  <p_month>5</p_month>
                  <p_day>15</p_day>
               </inception>
               <p_number>0</p_number>
               <attributes>
                              <att val="0" name="SVCsynchronouscall" />
                              <att val="2" name="value1" />
                              <att val="2017-5-15" name="Date" />
                              <att val="0" name="value2" />
                              <att val="0" name="value3" />
                              <att val="0" name="value4" />
               </attributes>
<warnings>

</warnings>
            </trans_request>
         </requests>
      </multitrans>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please share your xml string.

Comment: @SahilGulati i've added to my question

Comment: Which information you want to extract?

Comment: i must get all the nodes names. e.g. username, password,clientid, transtype, company, product, p_year etc and all the attributes names (e.g. SVCsynchronouscall, value1 etc)

Comment: Hope my post will help you out..

Comment: @SahilGulati yes your code is good and thank you very much. Nevertheless one issue is that all the attributes have name="something". This means that the array holds only the last value. And another one is that if i try a simpler XML

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <USER_NAME>XXXX</USER_NAME>
      <USER_PSWD>XXXX</USER_PSWD>
      <USE>XXXX</USE>
      <PROGRAM>XXXX</PROGRAM>
      <STARTDATE>XXXX</STARTDATE>
      <PERIOD>XXXX</PERIOD>
      <ENDPERIOD>XXXX</ENDPERIOD>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: i get no response, just a blank page

Comment: can you give me an examples which you want to extract other than this

Comment: Please see my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143967/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-dip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to find the innerHTML of `soap:Body`. And then we treating `innerHTML` in `simplexml_load_string` and converting it into array using `json_encode` and `json_decode`, and finally we are using `array_walk_recursive` to get all values.

[**Try another code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792173) `Demo for simple xml not-nested`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792189) `Demo for nested xml`

```
$string = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <multitrans xmlns="http://www.xxxx.xx/">
         <authentication>
            <username>xxxxxx</username>
            <password>xxxxxx</password>
            <clientid>xxxxxx</clientid>
         </authentication>
         <requests>
            <trans_request>
               <TransType tc="100"/>
               <company tc="500"/>
               <product tc="auto"/>
               <inception>
                  <p_year>2017</p_year>
                  <p_month>5</p_month>
                  <p_day>15</p_day>
               </inception>
               <p_number>0</p_number>
               <attributes>
                  <att val="0" name="SVCsynchronouscall" />
                  <att val="2" name="value1" />
                  <att val="2017-5-15" name="Date" />
                  <att val="0" name="value2" />
                  <att val="0" name="value3" />
                  <att val="0" name="value4" />
               </attributes>
            <warnings>
            </warnings>
            </trans_request>
         </requests>
      </multitrans>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
 $finalResult = array();
$domObject = new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadXML($string);

$domXPATH = new DOMXPath($domObject);
$results = $domXPATH->query("//soap:Body/*");

foreach($results as $result)
{
    if($result->childNodes->length==1 && $result->childNodes->item(0) instanceof  DOMText)
    {
        $finalResult[$result->tagName] = $result->textContent;
    }
    else
    {
        $array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($result->ownerDocument->saveXML($result))), true);
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($value,$key) use(&$finalResult)
        {
            if (!empty($value))
            {
                if(isset($finalResult[$key])&& is_string($finalResult[$key]) )
                {
                    $temp=$finalResult[$key];
                    $finalResult[$key] = array($temp,$value);
                }
                elseif(isset($finalResult[$key]) && is_array($finalResult[$key]) && count($finalResult[$key])>0)
                {
                    $finalResult[$key]=  array_merge(array($value),$finalResult[$key]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $finalResult[$key]=$value;
                }
            }
        });        
    }

}
print_r(array_filter($finalResult));
```

**output:**

```
 Array
(
    [username] => xxxxxx
    [password] => xxxxxx
    [clientid] => xxxxxx
    [tc] => Array
        (
            [0] => auto
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 500
        )

    [p_year] => 2017
    [p_month] => 5
    [p_day] => 15
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => value4
            [1] => value3
            [2] => value2
            [3] => Date
            [4] => SVCsynchronouscall
            [5] => value1
        )

    [val] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2017-5-15
        )
)
```